# Java Proxy Server Settings at JVM Level

Tags: java, facebook-graph-api, proxy

I have developed an java application which connect to facebook rest api and perform various tasks.

It has to run where is corporate proxy server, I have tried various JVM level proxy settings but did not work any for me. I have tried following

1.

```
System.setProperty("http.proxyHost", getHTTPHost());
System.setProperty("http.proxyPort", getHTTPPort());
System.setProperty("https.proxyHost", getHTTPHost());
System.setProperty("https.proxyPort", getHTTPPort());
```

2.

```
$> java -Dhttp.proxyHost=proxyhostURL 
-Dhttp.proxyPort=proxyPortNumber 
-Dhttp.proxyUser=someUserName 
-Dhttp.proxyPassword=somePassword HelloWorldClass
```

Can anybody tell me the working recipe?

Comment: Is the access to facebook api is allowed by the proxy?

Comment: Yes. it is allowed, I check in browser.

Comment: Are you getting any error/exception if so post that in the question.